# A theorem cited by Ambrosetti and Prodi

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

On page 115 of the book by Ambrosetti and Prodi (*A primer of Nonlinear Analysis*), the following functional analysis theorem is cited:

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $A$, $B$ two linear maps defined on a dense deomain $D \subset H$. Suppose that (i) $A$ is self-adjoint; (ii) $B$ is continuous and symmetric, in the sense that $(Bu|v)=(u|Bv)$ for all $u,v\in D$, and (iii) $T = \lambda I + A + B$ is invertible from $D$ to $H$ for some real $\lambda$. Then $A+B$ is self-adjoint.

The text bears no proof nor reference. Where can a proof be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result is a corollary of the following applied to the case where $\lambda$ is real:

> **Theorem:** Let $L : \mathcal{D}(L)\subseteq \mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$ be a densely-defined symmetric linear operator on a complex Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ for which $(L-\lambda I)$ and $(L-\overline{\lambda}I)$ are surjective for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$. Then $L$ is selfadjoint.

**Proof:** Let $L$ be as stated, and suppose $y \in \mathcal{D}(L^{\star})$. Then $(L-\overline{\lambda} I)z = (L^{\star}-\overline{\lambda}I)y$ for some $z\in\mathcal{D}(L)$, and
\begin{align}
       ((L-\lambda I)x,y) & =(x,(L^{\star}-\overline{\lambda}I)y) \\
                          & =(x,(L-\overline{\lambda})z) \\
                          & =((L-\lambda I)x,z),\;\;\; x\in\mathcal{D}(L).
\end{align}
The last equality follows because $L$ is symmetric on its domain, and $x,z\in\mathcal{D}(L)$. Therefore,
$$
             ((L-\lambda I)x,y-z)=0,\;\;\; x\in\mathcal{D}(L).
$$
However, $(L-\lambda I)$ is surjective as well. Thus $y=z \in \mathcal{D}(L)$. In other words, $\mathcal{D}(L^{\star})\subseteq \mathcal{D}(L)$; the symmetry of $L$ gives the opposite inclusion $\mathcal{D}(L)\subseteq\mathcal{D}(L^{\star})$. Hence, $\mathcal{D}(L)=\mathcal{D}(L^{\star})$, which implies that $L=L^{\star}$. $\blacksquare$